# IPアドレスのネットワーク部の求め方について

Tags: linux, network

IPアドレスでネットワーク部とホスト部があり、ネットワーク部を知りたいです。

#### 質問

DNSのAレコードで指定しているIPアドレスはクラスがわからず、サブネットマスクもなくCIDRもないです。いったいネットワーク部はどこになるのでしょうか？

どうように、nslookupしたとき↓やRailsのログでIPアドレスを出したときなどは、ネットワーク部を知りたいときはどのように知ればよいのでしょうか？どこがネットワーク部かしる情報が一緒に与えられてないのでわからないなと思っています。

$ nslookup google.com
Server:     192.168.11.1
Address:    192.168.11.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.161.238

#### 質問追記

先述の質問に加え、こちらも解説いただけると助かります
whois 172.217.161.238
とすると、CIDR表記がわかると教えてもらいました。私もその方も知りたいのですが、IPアドレスのみからどうやってCIDR表記を求めているのでしょうか

Comment: 例えば whois コマンドを使うと `whois 172.217.161.238`, `CIDR:           172.217.0.0/16` と表示されます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ということは、IPアドレス単体のみ、この場合だと172.217.161.238からでもどこがネットワーク部かわかるということですかね。どういう仕組で特定しているのでしょうか？

Comment: 仕組みについては私も知りたいと以前から思っていましたので、質問文に追記していただけますか？(詳しい方が回答して下さるかと思います)

Answer (score 5):

172.217.161.238が割り当てられているサーバー上の設定を直接確認する、172.217.161.238のサーバーが接続されたネットワークの設定を確認する、つまり、自分自身がGoogleのサーバーやネットワーク管理者である、と言ったことがない限り、実際にそのサーバーが所属するネットワークについてネットマスクがいくつなのか、そのIPのネットワーク部とホスト部がどれなのかはわかりません。

外部からわかる情報は172.217.0.0/16という範囲でGoogleにIPアドレスが割り当てられていると言うことだけです。Googleが/16をそのまま/16として使用しているとは限りません。172.217.0.0/24, 172.217.1.0/24, ..と/24で区切っている使っている可能性もあれば、3オクテットが2のところだけ、172.217.2.0/25, 172.217.2.128/25とさらに分割している可能性もあります。どのように分割しようがGoogleの自由であり、効率よくIPアドレスを使うためにどうすべきか考えるのはGoogleのネットワーク担当者の仕事です。とても小さな172.217.161.238/30の可能性もありますし、172.217.161.238/16そのままの可能性もあります。

なお、インターネット上のBGP等で流れるルーティング経路情報からある程度絞り込めます。たとえば、172.217.161.0/24がGoogleが管理しているあるルーターが目的地と言った風に広報されていた場合、/24よりは狭いだろうと推測は出来ますが、/24であるとは限りません。Googleが管理しているルーターから先で/25や/26でさらに分割されている可能性があります。しかし、それらの情報をインターネット上の第三者へ知らせる必要性はないため、BGP等で広報されることはありません。ここから先はGoogleに実際に聞かないとわからないことですが、セキュリティ上の理由によりネットワーク構成の詳細を第三者に教えるようなことは基本的にありません。

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます！大変良くわかりました！

Answer (score 3):

> IPアドレスのみからどうやってCIDR表記を求めているのでしょうか

何らかのアルゴリズムで求めているわけではなく、WHOISサーバからの応答メッセージに直接CIDRが記載されています（と期待できます）。

IPv4アドレス 172.217.161.238 を [APNICで検索](http://wq.apnic.net/static/search.html) すると、下記のような応答メッセージがWHOISサーバから返ってきます。

> ```
> NetRange: 172.217.0.0 - 172.217.255.255
> CIDR: 172.217.0.0/16
> NetName:  GOOGLE
> [...]
> ```

参考：https://www.nic.ad.jp/ja/newsletter/No34/0800.html

> WHOISプロトコルは、クライアントからのテキストによる問い合わせ要求に対し、TCPポート43で稼動するサーバがテキストで回答することを規定するのみの非常にシンプルなプロトコルで、回答フォーマットなどの規定はありません。従って、サービスを提供する組織の情報管理ポリシーごとにWHOISの仕様が定められ、運用されてきました。WHOISサーバによって回答のフォーマットが異なるのもそのためです。